# CloudKit error "Cannot modify production schema" despite schema in Production Environment

Tags: ios8, icloud, cloudkit

My app uses CloudKit private database to sync data. In Development Environment creating new CKRecordZone is succesfull.

When I test my app using Production Environment, **CKModifyRecordZones** operation returns error. I use Ad'hoc Deployment to address CK Production Enviroment.

I checked the following:

- Schema is deployed to Production environment
- Quering container about accountStatus returns CKAccountStatusAvailable

```
self.container accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error)
```

I use the following code to create CKRecordZone:

```objective-c
    CKRecordZone *recordZone = [[CKRecordZone alloc] initWithZoneName:DatabaseZoneName];

    CKModifyRecordZonesOperation *modifyOperation = [[CKModifyRecordZonesOperation alloc] initWithRecordZonesToSave:@[recordZone] recordZoneIDsToDelete:nil];
```

Errors received when testing in Production Environment:

> <Error>: Received error 48 from the server: <CKDPResponseOperationResultError: 0x1460fae0> {
>       clientError =     {
>           type = zoneNotFound;
>       };
>
> <Error>: Syntax error in request
>
> <CKError 0x16e2c130: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some record zones"
>
> ...:defaultOwner = CKError 0x16db8a60: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "Cannot modify production schema. Please use the CloudKit Dashboard to first deploy your schema from Development to Production.">

In CloudKit Dashboard I can see my schema deployend in Production Environment **(green background)**.

Any ideas what goes wrong?

Comment: And you are sure that the zone with the name DatabaseZoneName already existed when you deployed to the production environment? Because you can't create a new zone to the production environment. You should create the zones in the development environment and then deploy that schema to production

Comment: @edwin, Apple documentation says: "A CKRecordZone object defines an area for organizing related records in a database. The public and private databases have a single default zone, and in the private database you may create additional custom zones as needed.". Because this is private database (user specific), I can not create zone "in advance". So I believe calling CKModifyRecordZonesOperation in productive schema should succeed.

Comment: If you've double-checked that your app is pointing at production and the right container, then this might be a server bug where the container has gotten into a bad state. Does this happen if you create a new container and point your app at that? Either way, if you grab logs (https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/icloud/#icloud-drive) this would be good to have in a radar.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as you. I have another application using the same code and being working. I don't know why on my new application it is not working. Did you find a way to make it working?